# Use the same modal codes multiple times with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have the following modal in my HTML

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">-----</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ----
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">ശരി</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am triggering this modal using the following php-javascript combination based on the condition `$resultCheck > 0`

```html
if($resultCheck > 0){
   echo '<script>
   $("#exampleModalCenter").modal("show");
   </script>';
}
```

**What I need**

I need to use the same modal `exampleModalCenter` for different conditions Eg: `$resultCheck = 0` and so on with title and content changes according to the conditions. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Call ajax function to get dynamic content & fill the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use. You can change the Title and content based on the condition which triggers the modal.

For this utilize,

```
  $('#exampleModalCenterTitle').text('The replaced text.');
```

And you can do the same with the other contents.

Comment: Thanks Pasan. It works perfectly for title. But when I tried the same for the content, its not working. I used `$("#exampleModalCenterContent").text("The replaced text.");`. Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Can I know in between which tags (with the id of the tag) that you are going to put the new content?

Comment: title is the `modal-title` and content is the `modal-body`. I didn't give ID for these tags. Mentioned are the classes

Comment: I got it Pasan. Now i gave id to the content also and called that ID to change its text. Thank you